# Using Android and Maven

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I am using the Android Maven tutorial found [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBuildMaven/article.html). I have installed the m2e plugin for Eclipse. Now my src directory is slightly messed up. It read the src directory, and thinks the main/java directory as a package name. How can i correct this. Off course i just put the java directory as my src folder, but eclipse should recognize this as a maven project. When i use a web application this works, how can i force eclipse to do in case of an Android Application.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify in the pom.xml exactly where your java packages exist by adding sourceDirectory to the build section:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
</build>
```

The standard location for java packages within maven projects is to place them in src/main/java so sourceDirectory should only be required if using a different location, as with the tutorial:

```
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
```

You can put them where you like, as long as the pom is configured to point to the correct location.

btw, Intellij IDEA does a lot better dealing with maven project than Eclipse seems to do and [version 12](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/index.html) released next month has great Android functionality.